# How to Define Something that Acts as a Dictionary of Unique Functions in F#?

Tags: list, dictionary, f#

It is my understanding that a `Dictionary`'s elements must all be the same (ie: `unit -> unit`)

I need a way to add functions to an object, similar to a `Dictionary`, but my problem is that the functions have different Types. The only thing I can know for sure is that added functions will always follow a pattern of `int -> 'T` where `'T` could be any Type. All functions in the object could be made to inherit from a shared type if needed. Here is a non-functioning example of how it would be used.

```
let myFunctions = Dictionary<int,int -> unit>()

let exampleFunction0 (x : int) : int = x + 1
let exampleFunction1 (x : int) : byte = (byte)x
let exampleFunction2 (x : int) : string[] = Array.create<string> 1 "test"

myFunctions.Add(0, exampleFunction0)
myFunctions.Add(1, exampleFunction1)
myFunctions.Add(2, exampleFunction2)

let randomNumber = System.Random().Next(3)

let result x = myFunctions.Item(randomNumber) x
```

It is important to note that which one of the functions that gets called is random and I cannot know it. The purpose of the dictionary is to hold the functions that will be called randomly. As in the examples, the results are not the same as I need the results to be different for each function. `x` will always be the same, but the result of the function will not.

The code will be in a library to be reused, so functions may be added that I will never see.

Comment: What type would you expect `result x` to return?

Comment: Since it's impossible to know result type of function call, it should be `object`. Dictionary value should be of type `int -> object` and functions can be adapted with `box` function like `myFunctions.Add(2, exampleFunction2 >> box)`

Comment: @BrianBerns `result x` will probably, based on what I've learned in this question, return `object`. My issue with that would be how do I associate `object` with a more specific type like `int`, `unit`, or `myClass3`?

Comment: You can downcast an `object` to a more specific type using the [`:?>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/casting-and-conversions#downcasting) operator. E.g. `let myInt = result 1.0 :?> int`. But you have to know the type you're downcasting to at compile time.

Comment: @BrianBerns in my scenario the function is called randomly so type `int` would need to be passed to the downcast function. I tried this real quick, but, as you pointed out, the compiler is not happy about it.

Comment: You could use reflection to determine the specific return type at runtime instead, but that opens a big can of worms. It seems like  you're trying to write a dynamically-typed program, but F# is a statically-typed language. They don't mix well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to unify the output types to make this work.

If all the types are known you should use a Discriminated Union.

```
type ReturnValues = 
| Case0 of int
| Case1 of byte
| Case2 of string[]

let myFunctions = Dictionary<int,int -> ReturnValues>()

let exampleFunction0 (x : int) = x + 1 |> Case0
let exampleFunction1 (x : int) = (byte)x |> Case1
let exampleFunction2 (x : int) = Array.create<string> 1 "test" |> Case2

myFunctions.Add(0, exampleFunction0)
myFunctions.Add(1, exampleFunction1)
myFunctions.Add(2, exampleFunction2)

let randomNumber = System.Random().Next(3)

let result x : ReturnValues = myFunctions.Item(randomNumber) x
```

If you don't know all the types you can make all the return types `obj` (`Dictionary<int,int -> obj>`) using the `box` function or you can make all the return types implement a common interface.

Comment: @tranquility, the types are not known. There will be functions added in the future where `'T` is a new type created after this code is compiled.

Answer (score 0):

What has ultimately solved the problem for me is to package together the `Type` and `Object`. This package is what the functions that will be added to the dictionary must return. This way there is a standard way for new types to be added after compilation.

```
open System.Collections.Generic
open System

// a package that can hold an object and its type
type package(x, y) =
    member this.x : Type = x
    member this.y : Object = y

//empty class for testing
type testClass() = class end

//custom types for testing
type fiy(x) = 
    member this.Value : string = x
type foe(x) = 
    member this.Value : testClass = x

//functions for testing
let func0 (x: int) : package = package(typeof<int>, x)
let func1 (x: int) : package = package(typeof<fiy>, fiy("potato"))
let func2 (x: int) : package = package(typeof<foe>, foe(testClass()))

let myFunctions = Dictionary<int, (int -> package)>()

//example use of adding a function
myFunctions.Add(0, (func0))
myFunctions.Add(1, (func1))
myFunctions.Add(2, (func2))

//pick a random number to test with; as we will have no idea which function will be ran
let randomNumber = System.Random().Next(3)
let pickedFunction x : package = (myFunctions.Item(randomNumber) x)

let ranFunction = pickedFunction 5 //just some filler number to test with

printfn "The type of the ranFunction is: %s" (ranFunction.x.ToString())
```